# highchats heatmap how to show all categories on y-axis

Tags: highcharts, heatmap

I have 24 hours format values on y axis.I want to display all 24 categories on y-axis.But in heatmap highcharts display only odd number categories.what is the setting required to display all catagories?

Comment: could you add a fiddle or some code?

Comment: below is my fiddle link http://jsfiddle.net/bgity/h8y4d2pb/32/

Answer (score 1):

First of all you should remove the duplicates from you yCategories, it's not necessary, but you still have a lot of duplicates

```
var uniqueYCategories = yCategories.filter(function(item, pos) {
    return yCategories.indexOf(item) == pos;
})
```

then you set the step to 1

```
 yAxis: {
   categories: uniqueYCategories,
   labels:{
        step: 1 // this will show every second label
   }
 },
```

full fiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/h8y4d2pb/37/

Comment: HI  Liviu I have one problem is that all the total_tax values are not diplay in graph

Comment: in the fiddle you set them all to 0

Comment: please check this links http://jsfiddle.net/bgity/h8y4d2pb/47/.In this I set datalables enable so we see total_tax values.But it will display only even catageries and not for odd.I have to see for all rectangle.

Comment: your labels overlap, so you need to set allowOverlap: true, here is the full fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/h8y4d2pb/55/

Comment: Thanks its working perfectly.One more problem is that my right side heatmap bar is not displyed.